# Iterating through a datetime.datetime array in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using a variable `(cloudsat_time)` which comes as a `datetime.datetime` array.

```
array([datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 21, 8, 41, 21),
   datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 21, 8, 41, 21, 160000),
   datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 21, 8, 41, 21, 320000), ...,
   datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 21, 10, 20, 13, 640137),
   datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 21, 10, 20, 13, 799805),
   datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 21, 10, 20, 13, 959961)], dtype=object)
```

I want to iterate through each of these timesteps to get the maximum value of another variable (height) which I've tried to do with:

```
for timestep in cloudsat_time:
    timestep_list = []
    for height in timestep:
        timestep_list.append(height)
```

but I keep getting the error that `datetime.datetime is not iterable` when it runs the second `for` loop. Is there a way to iterate through the array?

Comment: You indicate that you want to get the maximum value of another variable `height`. How is that variable defined? What does it contain?

Comment: Sorry - this is modelling the atmosphere, so height is an array which correspond to cloud types going upwards

Comment: Why should `datetime` be iterable?

Comment: How about `max(cloudsat_time)` ?

Comment: Are the length of `height` and the length of `cloudsat_time` equal? If so, are you guaranteed that entry N of `height` corresponds to entry N of `cloudsat_time`?